# Extended Choice Parameter Groovy Script get Parameter Name in Value Field

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a groovy script that I use in the Extended Choice Parameter plugin to grab image names from artifactory. The image list it grabs is dependent on the name of the parameter.

For example if we have two parameters, one called `test-repo` the other `dev-repo`

The groovy script would look something like this:

```
   @Grapes(
   @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
)

import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

// the REPO_NAME below is test-repo or dev-repo depending on the parameter name
def query = 'items.find({**<REPO_NAME>**}).limit(1)'

def artifactoryURL = // the URL for artifactory

def restClient = new RESTClient(artifactoryURL)
restClient.setHeaders(['Authorization': 'Basic ' + "jenkins:password".getBytes('iso-8859-1').encodeBase64()])

def response = restClient.post(
   path: 'artifactory/api/search/aql',
   body: query,
   requestContentType: 'text/plain'
   )

response.getData().results.name
```

The problem is there are a lot of different repositories I need to reference and different artifactory URLs I might end up using.

So I was trying to find a way that I can reference the parameter name to be able to use it in the parameter value.

Something like this

```
def query = 'items.find({ params.key }).limit(1)'
```

Where `params.key` is the name of the parameter in this Extended Choice Parameter section.

I have tried using different ways to reference the parameter name but they don't seem to work.

I feel like I am trying to break the 4th wall by having a parameter value that references a parameter name prior to starting a build.

I was thinking about somehow trying to grab the instance of the Jenkins build and try to look at the parameter name but any such effort proved useless. I also tried using `this` or `it` hoping that groovy would grab the current instance of the parameter so I can reference `this.name` or `it.name` but none of it works.

EDIT (after hitting the 1,000 views mark):

I never found the solution to this. Instead for every extended choice parameter I have hard coded the repository name I want to get the images from.